# Is there a way to integrate custom help into the Office 2010 Help System?

Tags: office-2010, office-addins

I'm working in an Excel add-in. I want to add its own help. I don't care if it replaces the general Excel help - I want to know how.

What I was able to was to add custom help into VS 2010, using the Help Viewer. Does this work for office?

Also, if I had to add a button on the ribbon for the add-in, is there a way to make the information displayed online? I don't like including a file with the installer.

Thanks a lot, guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel's Help System is the Help 2.x System, which is different to the VS Help Viewer, a new Help System that will be included in new Microsoft applications.

To add help into the Help 2.x System in general you can use its plug-in mechanisms.

Finally, there is no way to make that help online. The help file must always be included with the add-in installer.

Luis Galeana.